# '...give us it.' [Can a pronoun as a direct object be placed at the very end of a sentence?]

Tags: pronouns, syntax, direct-objects

Can a pronoun as a direct object be placed at the very end of a sentence? As in

'...she was saying herself. Emails obtained. Just through honesty? Thrown(?through) and being given out? Because we have a transparent government? No, no, no. Through the Freedom of Information Act. That means that people had to go give us the information. Come on, **give us it.**'

Russell Brand at 02:40 in "So... They F*cking Knew All Along"

How often do you hear it in everyday speech?

Comment: This is an example of colloquial English as spoken in the UK. It's not standard English. Don't use it in an exam, or you will lose marks.  It means "give it to me"..

Comment: It's heard often in certain dialects in British English and never in American English.

Answer (score 1):

This is a colloquial British use of the pronoun "us" that actually means "me". You could understand this phrase as "*give **me** it*". It is a misuse of the word, because "us" is correctly a plural pronoun; yet this singular use for oneself is common in Lancashire, Yorkshire, and other regions. In some parts of Yorkshire, "us" is sometimes used in place of the determiner "*my*".

"*Give it to me*" would be the most grammatically correct imperative statement, but in casual speech both "*give it me*" and "*give me it*" are natural to native speakers.

Comment: "give it me" is actually "give it' me", isn't it?

Comment: @tes389 Are you using an apostrophe to show a shortening? I haven't seen it written like that before. You might be thinking of another regional colloquialism from Yorkshire which is the shortening of the words "to" and "the" to just a "t" sound. In writing where you are trying to indicate such an accent, you might write, for example, "*down t' pub*". But as I said, "give it me" is natural to a native speaker, there is no need to indicate any shortening.

Comment: *Give me it* is "standard". *Give it me* (omitting the preposition *GIve it **to** me*) is "dialectal / colloquial" BrE. But that's a *nationwide* usage, whereas reducing ***to the*** to just ***t'*** in *I'm going down t' pub* is exclusively *Northern* UK regional dialect.

Comment: @fumblefingers I'm Northern and I don't say it. I think you've tried to repeat what I already said but in doing so made it into a sweeping generalisation.

Comment: Saying a feature is "exclusively Northern UK regional dialect" does not in any way imply that all Northern UK dialect has the feature - it means other dialects do not.    (It especially does not when the specific subregions it is heard are mentioned!)

Comment: @BadZen How many 'northern' accents do you think there are? The colloquialism being discussed is not present in all northern accents. It's typically found in 2 of the 12 northern counties, and not in all areas of those. I named the area where it is most dominant, which is why reframing that as "northern accents" is a generalisation.

Comment: @Astralbee: I didn't mean *all* Northerners talk about *going down t' pub* - by "exclusively", I meant Southerners / "Midlanders" *never* use that form (it only really occurs in Lancashire / Yorkshire / Tyneside dialect). As opposed to discarding the preposition completely in ***give it me***, which occurs (somewhat sporadically) *everywhere*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know who says it and who doesn't. I said so in my comment. What I don't understand is why you essentially rewrote my comment but replaced Yorkshire for "the north".

Comment: I don't understand your hostile attitude. I *expanded* on your comment to clarify that complete deletion of ***to*** in *Give it me* is "uneducated / dialectal" *everywhere* in the UK, whereas the reduction from ***to the*** to ***t'*** is location-specific. Lighten up, willya? None of it was for your benefit anyway.